# Notification sound

Tags: feature-request, notifications, audio

How about a self refreshing notification area with a beep sound?

When I'm very active in other sites, testing or researching to solve questions, I miss some notifications from the network (I have questions and answers in more than 1 site).

I think its considerable to have notifications self updating at a 1 or 2 minutes rate and play a sound if there are some new notifications. With a setting to enable this feature for the one's that require it, of course.

Something like Facebook implemented a time ago would, but with an opt-in option as I've said above.

Comment: For Facebook, the deeply meaning for sound notification is: "please please please check me. Why don't you keep surfing Fb and get distracted from your work?". And that's the reason why this question get downvoted, I think. But sometimes, in SE, we DO need a notification to check back. So here my solution: have a button "Get sound notification" on each question we ask or each answer we would like to notice new comments. And the sound shouldn't be in high pitch so that it won't interrupt any flowing idea in our minds. Just enough so that we can hear and decide to ignore it or not.

Answer (score 4):

I get sound notifications when I get new messages in my inbox with the Stack Exchange app ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8)) installed on my phone and on my tablet. I did not have to do anything special to get the notifications.

Comment: I use Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3):

Use the StackExchange API and then show us how cool it is, sound beeping would annoy me, task bar notification maybe not so much.

Comment: Lets see if there're some people that think it's a good idea. Anyway, that was the reason I've stated a setting to ENABLE this feature for those who may want.

Comment: I would very much like a sound notification because I always interrupt my programming to come in and check for new answers. If there was a sound notification I would be programming peacefully knowing that I will not miss anything and not have to check every 5 minutes :)

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but saing "Do it yourself" wont help new ideas to come. Besides, the suggestion included an opt-in feature.

Comment: @rcdmk Dont get me wrong, I too welcome MSO getting new feature requests and people submitting their idea's. I wanted my answer to encourage you to show us how cool the concept would be by referring you to the API. Also I didn't downvote the you. I was mearly saying this can be done using the API. Who knows the you could make a tiny bit of cash doing it.

Comment: @JeremyThompson If it's that so I've got you wrong. Not a problem, man. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a lot of dev work for this, as sound can be tricky in different browsers. Then there's mobile to consider, screen readers, other considerations, etc.

Even without the masses of dev work, this would introduce a check required by the site scripts to check *every user's* settings when sending notifications, to see if they have sound enabled or not.
This introduces additional overhead from *every user* regardless of their having it enabled or not.

I doubt this would be a welcomed feature by most users for many different reasons:

- Uses Stack at work, can't have *bleeps* in the office
- Don't want to be disturbed
- Hate bleepy websites
- User has little activity on the sites so would get very little
  notifications, so pointless
- Are happy with the top of the page visual notifications as they are
  easy to see
- Don't have speakers, or not switched on by default
- More

You will need to give a *much* stronger case to get some upvotes - really good arguments why this would be good, and why you think many would use it, very beneficial, etc.